# web service call and JSON array manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sencha-touch, arrays

I need to call a web service from javascript that returns a JSON array in the following format:

```
["hello","there","I","am","an","array"]
```

Unfortunately, the javascript library I'm using (Sencha Touch) to load this data into a widget doesn't accept that format as data input.  It will work with something like this however:

```
[["hello"],["there"],["I"],["am"],["an"],["array"]]
```

So there are two questions here-- how can I call that web service in javascript and then manipulate the returned array into the format I need?  I've been looking at jQuery's getJson() method, not sure if that's the way to go or if there are better ways.

The URL that delivers the JSON array is this  [right here.](http://fastmotorcycleservice.cloudapp.net/FastMotorCycleListService.svc/list/Bruno)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jsFiddle showing both parts of what you asked about. I'm using jQuery for my AJAX call (faked in the jsFiddle) and I'm using Underscore.js for the manipulation:

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/E7YTQ/

```
// Part 1: Get the raw data. Unfortunately, within a jsFiddle I can't go get it from a different domain. So I'm
// simulating the call instead.
var rawDataPromise = $.ajax({
    url : "/echo/json/",
    data : fakeData,
    type : "POST"
});
// var rawDataPromise = $.ajax("http://fastmotorcycleservice.cloudapp.net/FastMotorCycleListService.svc/list/Bruno");

rawDataPromise.done(
  function (results) {
    // Part 2: Manipulate the data into the form we need.
    var manipulatedResults = _.map(results, function (item) { return [ item ]; });

    console.log(manipulatedResults);
  }
);

// You could also pull that together into a single call $.ajax(...).done(function (results) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

once you have the data in one of your local variables you can manipulate it as you want:

```
var data = the_function_you_use_to_get_data();
var formatted_array = new Array();
for(i in data){
    var d = new Array();
    d[0] = i;
    formatted_array.push(d);
}
```

i hope it answered your question